# Reversing an Array

Tags: java

I wrote code to reverse an integer array. Code is as shown below:

```
public class ReverseArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int[] arr = new int[5];
            arr[0] = 1;
            arr[1] = 2;
            arr[2] = 3;
            arr[3] = 4;
            arr[4] = 5;
            for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length/2; i++)
                int temp = arr[0];
                arr[0] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
                arr[arr.length - i - 1] = temp;
            }
            System.out.println(arr);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not reversing the array.. I'm getting following output.

```
 [I@3bad086a
```

I don't see anything wrong with my logic.

Comment: You're printing the array reference, not each item in the array. Consider iterating over the array again and printing each element.

Comment: I changed the for loop condition like this. for(int i=0;i<=arr.lenth/2;i++)

Comment: An array is an object, hence it is a reference to a memory location. What you're seeing when you call `println` on your array is the location in memory where the first element of the array is stored, as a hexadecimal number. If you want to see the elements of the array you should write another function `printArray` which loops through the array and calls `println` on the elements individually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is printing out the *reference* to the array.
If you print out the array one element at a time, you will see the reversed array.

EDIT:
Two more points.

1. You're using `arr[0]` when you intend to use `arr[i]`.
2. More insidious: you're iterating *too much*. You only need to iterate until `arr.length / 2`. Since this is a homework question, I leave it to you to find out why; try printing out the intermediate results and explaining them.

Answer (score 6):

A goody:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 3):

u need to loop through the array to print it

```
for (int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
```

Firstly , i will let the above code remain (it is wrong (`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`), and now i believe it was good that you down-voted me )

```
public class ReverseArray {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int[] arr = new int[5];
            arr[0] = 1;
            arr[1] = 2;
            arr[2] = 3;
            arr[3] = 4;
            arr[4] = 5;
            for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length/2; i++){            
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
                arr[arr.length - i - 1] = temp;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length -1 ; i++){ 
                    System.out.println(arr[i]);
                    }                
            }          
         catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

For now , i will make a few simple suggestions

1. the {} were missing around the for loop.
2. instead of traversing the whole array , you only need need to go through half of it, so the  arr.length/2

Comment: For homework answers, IMO it's better to provide direction, rather than cut-and-paste answers. Also nicer to use real words instead of SMS speak.

Comment: really disappointed at the down-vote. i just provided the solution for the immediate problem . IMHO i gave him the direction to print and then get back to us if his logic was right or wrong . If i had commented on his logic this early , i might as well give him the entire code .

Comment: 3 votes for the comment that down-vote was harsh , yet no one reversed it ..i expect SO to keep up the standards .

Comment: Well, one of the votes was yours :p There's nothing intrinsically wrong with downvoting your answer, though--it's indented poorly and uses text-msg-speak. Voting is designed to reward well-crafted answers, or indicate when the voter doesn't feel it's up to par. That said, as with any public site, there will always be some level of seemingly-random voting; just have to live with it :)

Comment: The downvote was mine. Why don't you edit your answer and improve it so that I could remove the downvote in good conscience?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Arrays.toString(arr)` for that.
Arrays don't have specific implementation of `toString()`, so calling it results in the default `toString` implementation of Object. In Java5 the `toString` functionality was added for arrays, as a static method in Arrays class. I guess that it wasn't added to arrays directly due to backward compatibility considerations.

And by the way, you have a small bug in the code. I believe you want to swap values in indexes `length-i-1` and `i` (not `0`).

Answer (score 1):

you need to print the contents of the array not the array itself. try using a loop to iterate over the array and print each int one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

use following to print your array

```
for (int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
               System.out.println(arr[i]);
            }
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
for (int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing

```
System.out.println(arr);
```

This will going to print memory location of variable arr.

You should try

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

Comment: (Modulo the typo, but at least if he cuts-and-pastes this, he'll have to track down the error.)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding printing the array, several of the previous answers are correct. However, your code still doesn't work. You need to replace `arr[0]` with `arr[i]` in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the easiest approaches to reverse an array in Java.

```
package reversearray;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

final public class Main
{
    private Object reverseArray(Object[]arr)[]
    {
        List<Object>list=Arrays.asList(arr);
        Collections.reverse(list);
        return(list.toArray());
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Object[] arr ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        arr=new Main().reverseArray(arr);        

        int newArray[]=new int[arr.length];  //Array of your desired type.

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            newArray[i]=Integer.valueOf(arr[i].toString());
        }

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(newArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can simply use with [Commons.Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) as follows.

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(int[] arr)
```

---

Using [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Collections.reverse(Ints.asList(arr));
```

Answer (score -1):

from my limited recall of C

```
for i = (length( array ) -1 ) to 0
  { print( array( i ) ; i-- }
```

NOTE: you are counting ELEMENTS not BYTES
ALSO: you subtract 1 from length because you are counting down to ZERO not 1

Comment: That just prints the elements in reverse order, doesn't reverse them in the array.